# Is there a way to align a logo to be in the center of a navigation bar?

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

Currently I am able to add the logo to the navigation bar, but it seems to be starting at the same height of the text, resulting in it not being in the middle vertically.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/408GV.png

I've tried some different alignments as class, however none have worked.

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
         <a class="navbar-brand" href="Home">
             <img src="https://i.imgur.com/hTiYNNe.png" width="53" height="35" class="d-inline-block align-top ml-2" alt="">
             <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
             <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

What I expect to happen is the logo to be there as a sort of "Home" button, which works, but it isn't centered.

Comment: The only valid children of `<ul>` are `<li>`s (you have to wrap your `<a>` in a `<li>`). Also, you have to close your `<a>`. Close it after the `<img>` if you want the image to link to `"Home"`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect use case for flexbox's `align-items: center` property. It vertically centers its flex children relative to the parent container.

**HTML**

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
         <li><a class="navbar-brand" href="Home">
             <img src="https://i.imgur.com/hTiYNNe.png" width="53" height="35" class="d-inline-block align-top ml-2" alt=""/></a></li>
             <li>About</li>
             <li>Contact</li>
           </ul>
     </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.nav {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 16px 32px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  height: 75px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

I've cleaned up your HTML and added some very basic styling to demonstrate.

See here for working example:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QPdzMN

But this looks like a Bootstrap project. Bootstrap 3? So you may not wish to override the default styling. Is that the case?